# How to use context when overriding __new__ to return an initialized object

Tags: python

I've implemented a factory class which returns an initialized class in the `__new__` method

```
class MyFactory(object):
    def __new__(self, my_obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if my_obj == ...:
            return A(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return B(*args, **kwargs)
```

Both classes `A` and `B` extend a base class `MyBase()` which support context

```
class MyBase(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        ...

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        ...
```

I'm trying to use this setup like this

```
with MyFactory(my_obj, ...) as something:
   something.do_something()
```

However an error is thrown obviously since python is expecting the `__enter__`, `__exit__` pair to be present on the `MyFactory` class

What changes should I make to make the above usage possible?

EDIT:

I concede, this is actually the correct way to do it. My errors were due to not returning `self` in the `__enter__` method :facepalm:

[Heres the working code for those of you interested](https://repl.it/repls/FirstLoathsomeSite)

Comment: If a `.__new__()` method returns something that isn't an instance of the containing class, then *that class plays no further part in the functionality of the returned object*.  In other words, there's no point in `MyBase` even being a class, as it never acts as one - it might as well be a plain function.  I believe you're misunderstanding the reason for the error that is thrown, but since you didn't actually include the error traceback I can't be sure.

Comment: it should work. try assigning the result object to a variable first and then use it in the with block to see if also tbdow the error

Answer (score 2):

Currently MyFactory only extends `oject`

```
class MyFactory(object):
```

I think your MyFactory object needs to extend MyBase using the following syntax:

```
class MyFactory(MyBase):
    ...
```

This should enable the superclass instantiation of the `__exit__` and `__enter__` methods without explicitly describing them again in the child classes.

It's a bit of a mashup, but since you're returning objects from the `__new__` call then it's probably a fair one.